# Rails defining Current_page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to use a basic current_page method to define whether a navigation link should be highlighted as the current page or not.

I am not receiving any errors at the moment but am clearly not defining things properly as it's not using my CSS correctly.

In my PagesController I have the following:

```
def current_page
  current_page = (path)
end
```

and I am using an if and else statement on my pages view to try and define which CSS line to use which looks like this:

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <% if "current_page" %>
        <a href="/about" class="about-cp">About</a>
      <% else %>
        <a href="/about" class="about">About</a>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

I have read quite a few forums on this but still can't seem to get it right.

Comment: That method should almost certainly go in a helper, not the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mhh you got an error in your code. With `if "current_page"` you will get always true, and only the first link will get rendered. You should use `if current_page` instead.

But rails has a build in helper, called `current_page?` for exactly this purpose:

Just do it like this:

```
 <% if current_page?(path) %>
   <a href="/about" class="about-cp">About</a>
 <% else %>
   <a href="/about" class="about">About</a>
 <% end %>
```

See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F) for more information on `current_page?`

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick respone, I am having some trouble now with the following error: `undefined local variable or method 'path'`. Do you know how I can define the path?

Comment: Could you post the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: All my routes when raked are showing the exact same format as this  `GET /about(.:format) {:action=>"about", :controller=>"pages"}`. They are all GET methods with an action which is the page name and calling the same controller. Sorry I would post it fully but there's not enough room in comments. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I hoped you would edit your question :P There should be one more field before the GET, this is the path. But you can feed the `current_page?` anything, a url, a hash with action and controller or the path. So `current_page?( :action => params[:action], :controller => params[:controller] )` will check if the page you are rendering ( the current page ) is the one you requested.

Answer (score 2):

The klump's answer follows your requirement, but I dare to propose a different approach:

```
 <div id="nav">
  <ul>
   <li>
     <%= link_to_unless_current 'About', about_path %>
   </li>
  </ul> 
 </div>
```

This way your `About` will appear as a text if current page is `about_path` and as a link on any other.

Comment: lol! I knew about ´link_to_unless´ and so on, but not about ´link_to_unless_current´. That is really nice!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I did initially have a setup similar to this with basic `link_to's` in place but because I am using CSS tween buttons that require call a background image for the mouse hover state I wasn't sure how to incorporate this with rails :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/about" class="<%= "active" if current_page?(path) %>">About</a>
```